# NFC card reader getting error android

Tags: android, nfc

Trying to read a NFC card using this -

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                NdefMessage[] msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
                NdefMessage msg = msgs[0];
                try {
                    byte[] payload = msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload();
                    String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 0200) == 0) ? String.valueOf(R.string.utf_8) : String.valueOf(R.string.utf_16);
                    int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0077;
                    String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");
                    Log.d("reader", "Language code:" + languageCode);
                    //Get the Text
                    String text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
                    textViewLastResult.setText(text);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            //textViewLastResult.setText("Wrong mime type: " + type);
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error in the line -

**String text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);**

> W/System.err: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: 2131099684
>   10-27 21:41:52.606 7804-7804/com.geniuslead.attendance W/System.err:     at java.nio.charset.Charset.forNameUEE(Charset.java:316)
>   10-27 21:41:52.606 7804-7804/com.geniuslead.attendance W/System.err:     at java.lang.String.(String.java:223)
>   10-27 21:41:52.606 7804-7804/com.geniuslead.attendance W/System.err:     at com.geniuslead.attendance.ui.ReadCardActivity.resolveIntent(ReadCardActivity.java:198)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you take the encoding from string resources. Instead, try to use something like this (depending on the version):

```
String text = "";
    if ((payload[0] & 0200) == 0)  text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    else text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

Comment: W/System.err: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=18; regionStart=15; regionLength=2131099684

Comment: another error it may be a bad decision whether to use UTF-8 or UTF 16.

Comment: I just put a Log on textEncoding I am getting value of 2131099684

Comment: I do not knowhn 2131099684, but doc says encoding unsupported. Try to test it on some simple text for ASCII, UTF8, UTF16. how did you figure out that the mask ((payload [0] & 0200) == 0) mean utf8?

`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/UnsupportedEncodingException.html`

Answer (score 1):

It is my mistake I was `String.valueOf(R.string.utf_8)` which is giving some no. might be string id. I hardcoded "UTF-8" Now it's working ..

Comment: Therefore, I wrote, try it over enum StandardCharsets.UTF_8 and you wrote that did not help?

Comment: That was giving diff error. any way I accept your ans thanks man. Please upvote my ans too.